# digitally sign pdf in browser

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, pdf, digital-signature

we are trying to digitally sign pdf on a browser probably using js.
the only good link i could find is this 
http://acrobatusers.com/forum/javascript/javascript-digitally-sign-multiple-pdf-documents-batch-processing
have you found the answer to this problem ? did you successed in that task.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [DigiSigner](http://www.digisigner.com/icepdf_viewer_with_add_ons.html). It is a PDF viewer with digital signature functionality. It is implemented in java, so it can run also as an applet in the browser on the client's side. There are demos, which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Java applets are no more supported by modern browsers. Use Browser Extensions for digitally signing using modern browser. Signer.Digital Chrome Extension is one such free extension provided by my company.

Answer (score 1):

We used the combo JavaApplet + [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on exact architecture of your solution, i.e. where the document is located and where the certificates are located. If you have a server-side solution and the document is on the server and you need to sign it using client's certificate, then you need to involve distributed signing. This is possible using PDFBlackbox pacakge of our SecureBlackbox product with distributed cryptography add-on which offers client-side modules (activex, flash control, java applet) for distributed data signing.

Comment: well we want the client to upload the pdf then it will be sign on the client computer and then it will be sent to us

Comment: @guyl The term "upload" is usually used for transferring the file from the client to the server. So probably you want the client to download the PDF and sign it on the client side. Now about signing itself - this is a non-trivial procedure, which can't be accomplished using pure Javascript. You would need to create some browser module (or more likely a combination of ActiveX control and a Java applet for different browsers) which will include some PDF signing library.

Comment: actually the pdf belongs to the client ... we need it to be uploaded to our servers already signed,

Comment: @guyl well, my previous comment applies.